# How to remove outside circle from material checkbox

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

My HTML

```html
<mat-checkbox id="includeBoundingBoxWithImage"        
    [(ngModel)]="includeBoundingBoxWithImage" color="primary"></mat-checkbox>
```

I have tried below CSS but it does not remove the outside circle

```css
.mdc-checkbox__ripple {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ripple you've selected is the circle that is shown when you hover over the checkbox. The one that is visible when you click the checkbox has the following selector: `.mat-mdc-checkbox-ripple`, so to remove both, you can do:

```css
.mat-mdc-checkbox-ripple,
.mat-mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox__ripple {
  display: none;
}
```

Tested on Angular material 17

Comment: I have tried this its still not working.

Comment: Sorry, missed one style, try now. If it's still not working,where did you put this style?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

Workaround fix would be:
.mat-ripple { display: none; }

or .mat-checkbox-ripple only for checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below CSS, to apply based on the id field. you can also wrap the checkbox inside a div and add a class to scope the changes only to that checkbox!

```
[ng-reflect-id='includeBoundingBoxWithImage'] .mdc-checkbox__ripple {
  display: none !important;
}

[ng-reflect-id='includeBoundingBoxWithImage']
  .mat-ripple.mat-mdc-checkbox-ripple.mat-mdc-focus-indicator {
  display: none !important;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/5sfw3h-jljdye?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fexample%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.ts)